# Outrageously long cold start on api gateway only?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple python function behind api gateway. On a cold start, the lambda executes in under 300 ms as determined from the cloudwatch logs, but it takes 13.99 seconds for api gateway to return the event. On subsequent calls, it returns in 350 ms to the api gateway endpoint.

This lambda function is inside of a vpc, and I'd like to keep it there for DB security. There are other lambda functions that execute fine with identical networking config, so that's not the issue. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Are the other Lambdas also in the same VPC?

Comment: yes, the other lambdas are also in the same vpc and they respond in less than 1 second, same nat gateway, same security groups etc. Identical networking config.

Comment: furthermore, they are using the same api gateway with the same method (post) but a different resource

Comment: As this is the case then, as Daniel mentioned, the cause is almost definitely the Lambda/VPC/Cold-start/slow ENI allocation issue. We operate in a regulated environment and run our Lambdas in VPCs and we solve the cold ENI allocation by keeping our Lambdas hot with CloudWatch events triggering them with null events once per minute. The function invokes, has all the networking etc, but doesn’t actually execute because the event is empty. Billing works out to be ~100ms/minute.

Comment: Thanks for the info on cold ENI allocation; that makes a lot of sense with the problems I have been having. Didn't realize there were 2 levels of cold start! Will try a setup where 1 of my lambda functions within the vpc is kept warm for the ENI cold start (10-15 s; completely unacceptable) and will just accept the other lambda cold starts (100-300 ms; very acceptable). Will report back my findings for future users.

Comment: Good luck; fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VPC lambdas have notoriously long cold start times. You are mistaken though; you've always been paying the VPC penalty. The lambda execution time you are seeing in Cloudwatch logs does not include the cold start time; that execution time is a reflection of the time that you are charged while the lambda is actually executing. You don't get charged for the time it takes for the lambda container to spin up, acquire an ENI, etc.

A more accurate picture of how long it takes for a VPC lambda to cold start would be the API Gateway "Integration latency" metric in Cloudwatch. There's hope though; AWS plans to redesign how lambdas in VPCs acquire their ENIs and make that process much faster. [You can read about that here.](https://www.nuweba.com/AWS-Lambda-in-a-VPC-will-soon-be-faster)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link. In case it gets broken later: "A VPC creates a network perimeter around AWS resources, restricting their access to outside resources such as the internet and other AWS services. In order to run a Lambda inside of a VPC, an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) must be created, an IP address must be allocated to the ENI, then the ENI is attached to the Lambda. According to the AWS documentation, this incurs an additional startup penalty that can take as long as 10 seconds"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the ENI cold start. For anyone who reaches this problem in the future, how I solved it was I triggered all of the lambda functions that required VPC connectivity every 14 minutes with cloudwatch events. The long starts have been fixed. This link pointed me towards the fact that the connection is kept alive for 15 minutes for lambdas within VPC: https://www.jeremydaly.com/lambda-warmer-optimize-aws-lambda-function-cold-starts/